# How to get the id of each object from a php foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Using a foreach loop in php I'm trying to retrieve data from a database. The idea is to display data, such as a title, from a database using a foreach loop in order to get the data into objects / divs.

Here is the example:
[image: result example]

This is the database (database->posts):
[image: database example]

I'm using a mysql query to get the data:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$postQuery = $db->query("
        SELECT 
        posts.id, 
        posts.title

        FROM posts

        GROUP BY posts.id
        ");

    while($row = $postQuery->fetch_object()){
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
```

And then I display the data using a foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
<div><?php echo $post->title; ?>
etc.
</div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Everything seems to work, except when I try to use the posts.id in a mysql query to check the content of the table in the databse with the corresponding posts.id. Is there a way to retrieve the id to use it in a query or php function?

Comment: `$post->id;` is what you looking for, this will work only inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm aware of that. The point is that $post->id doesn't work outside foreach for some reason.

Comment: It depends on what you looking for.. That doesn't work because you are creating an array in your `while` loop, than using it in a `foreach`.

Comment: So let's say I want to use a variable like $test that refers to a query outside of the loop, which is trying to use the post->id to see if there is something in the databse with the id and another column. Would that be possible?

Comment: As Shadow mentioned in his answer, you can use `$posts[x]->id` where `x` is the element you can use to identify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you can reference the ids as `$post->id` within the foreach loop (following your coding convention), or `$posts[x]->id` outside of the foreach loop, where x is the index of the element within the $posts array.

However, in sql you can join tables on certain fields, so you do not have to retrieve the posts.id column just to send those ids back as part of an sql request. See mysql's documentation on [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) for more details.

You should remove the `group by posts.id` from your query, it is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a way to use $post->id outside of the foreach loop? Or do i have to call the query inside of the loop? or would it be possible to set a var that refers to the query outside of the loop?

Comment: @Polymelon please do not add code in the comments, you can edit your question.

Comment: It is. Updated the the 1st sentence of my answer.

Comment: I can't get it to work. If I leave the brackets empty it returns an internal server error, but what am I supposed to set as a possible index?

Comment: Whichever post's id you want to retrieve. I'm sorry, but I cannot possibly guess what you would like to do. I think you should get a good book on php programming and start from the beginning. I also suggested already that you may not even need to reference the post's id within php, you can use joins in sql to get the corresponding data from other tables.